# How to trigger an event when a Circuit Bot is newly added to a Circuit Conversation

Tags: circuit-sdk

Whenever a Circuit Bot is getting added to a Circuit conversation, I want to trigger an event like,

1) A Bot introducing itself.
2) Send some Circuit Forms to get some info etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do so :

### JS SDK

If you use the JS SDK to implement your bot, you can subscribe to the event

```
// register a webhook to listen to new items added
await fetch(`${DOMAIN}/rest/v2/webhooks`, {
  method: 'POST',
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    body: `url=${encodeURI(`${URL}/webhook`)}&filter=CONVERSATION.CREATE`
});
```

Doing so, every time your bot is added to a conversation, you will receive an event and you can then execute the logic to post a welcome message or form

### Rest API

Use the Rest API to subscribe to the same CONVERSATION.CREATE event and, same as option 1, when the bot is added to a conversation, your webhook Url will be triggered.

Comment: Minor correct, the filter is CONVERSATION.CREATE as seen here https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/swagger/ui/index.html